# Easiest way for a polymer-element to declare a bindable property with a getter/setter?

Tags: polymer

Using an polymer-element's `attributes` attribute or `publish` block, it's very easy to create an attribute whose underlying storage is automatically managed. However, cases often come up where a property's value is not simply stored and retrieved. For example, a property's value may depend upon other element state. Another example: a property that's bindable but read-only.

In such cases, it's nice to be able to define a property with a getter/setter pair. However, it's not clear how to declare the resulting property as bindable. If the property name is included in `attributes` or `publish`, the getter/setter won't get used. If the property name *isn't* declared, it doesn't appear to be bindable. And the default property behavior that results from `attributes`/`publish` only supports an onChanged handler; there's no way to reject an attempt to set a property (e.g., in a setter), nor does there seem to be a way to have a getter run when the value is retrieved.

I assume that any solution here requires setting aside Polymer's declarative syntax(es) and building things from scratch. I took a shot at this: http://jsbin.com/qejaf/2/edit. That works, but I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this. E.g., is it possible to define a getter/setter (or just getter) *and* expose it via a `publish` block?

(Aside: there's a point in that example where I'd like to be able to refer to a named element constructor, but it doesn't appear to be available during `ready`.)

Comment: Just realized that even the jsbin, as given, doesn't completely work. If you try to embed the test-element in another element, then bind to the test-element's `count` property, the binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points:

- As of now you cannot publish a getter because Polymer doesn't have
  machinery to support it. We may improve this in the future, but it's 
  less important as it may seem as you can do similar work with computed
  properties and observers. There are definitely plans afoot to have
  a formal computed property syntax, this should make things a bit clearer.
- In general, you should not try to observe a getter, because (as Jan
  noted) `Object.observe` has no way of knowing if the value has changed
  (confusingly, it does often work under the `observe.js` polyfill because 
  of dirty checking; even so, dirty checking a getter is a bad idea
  because the getter could be an arbitrarily expensive calculation
  [e.g. might use `offsetWidth` and force a style recalc]).
- Making a bindable property read-only is not well supported. Polymer has taken an unusual approach by making data binding two-way by default. This approach was chosen as a way to reduce cognitive load on developers (data does not *propagate*, all bound properties simply always reflect the same value). The flip side of this is that observation side-effects are always *asynchronous*. In the following jsbin, I've made `count` read-only, but only in the sense that it snaps back to the private value asynchronously to any attempt to set it.

http://jsbin.com/qiboq/4/edit

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have a number of cases where it'd be helpful to allow people to bind to a read-only property. I'm specifically interested in supporting users who want to write markup but not JavaScript. For such users, observers don't help, because they require code. Instead, I'd like to let such users set up bindings declaratively. I hope your plans to support (bindable) computed properties go forward, and look forward to seeing those take shape.

Comment: It's not clear how you imagine users creating computed properties without using JavaScript. Maybe you could explain further.

Comment: I want component authors (producers) to be able to write components in JavaScript that expose computed, read-only properties. I want users (consumers) of those components to be able to bind to those properties in markup.

Comment: "There are definitely plans afoot to have a formal computed property syntax, this should make things a bit clearer." Is that the Polymer 1.0 syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to make out your complete question but it is pretty easy to use getter with publish property and attribute in polymer pls refer to sample below code

```
<polymer-element name="blog-element"  attributes="owner ownnerfullname">
<template >
  <div><span>{{owner}}</span></div>
      <div><span>{{ownnerfullname}}</span></div>
      </template>
 <script>
    Polymer('blog-element', {
       publish: {
        owner: 'I am foo!',
        get ownnerfullname(){return this.owner + "changes";}
      },


    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: This is helpful; I hadn't known you could define a getter within a publish block. But as far as I can see, a binding to a getter (like ownerfullname) won't automatically update when the element's internal state changes. There's no way for the element to indicate that the internal state has changed.